# android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS y politica de privacidad

Tags: android, android-studio

He actualizado el apk de una de mis app y me ha salido el mensaje de

> Tu APK solicita los siguientes permisos: **android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS**. Las aplicaciones que utilizan estos permisos en un APK deben tener configurada una política de privacidad.

Pero yo no tengo ese permiso en mi app, en el manifest estos son los permisos que tengo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

No entiendo porque me dice eso, he buscado el permiso GET_ACCOUNTS por toda mi app y no está, además yo nunca lo he añadido.
¿Alguien sabe porque me sale eso?

Comment: ¿Porque se esta requiriendo? Bueno porque probablemente usas una library que lo requiere como GCM (versiones anteriores). Que dependencias tienes en tu build.gradle?

Comment: Encontré la solución lo comento por si alguien le es de ayuda. 
El problema está en usar com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0
Que utiliza el permiso GET_ACCOUNTS

Comment: Agrega tu respuesta Hugo, puede ser de gran ayuda a otros!, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución:
El problema está en usar com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0
Que utiliza el permiso GET_ACCOUNTS

Answer (score 0):

Desde [Android 6.0 API 23](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) este es uno de los [permisos](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) que necesitas pedir en tiempo de ejecución.

La razón es que esta definido como un [tipo de permiso "riesgoso":](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **¿Porque se esta requiriendo?** Bueno porque probablemente usas una library que lo requiere como `GCM` (versiones anteriores).

---

Para requerir permisos:

Requerir permisos en Android 6.0 o posterior.

Este sería la forma de requerir permisos para poder obtener información de contactos en Android 6.0 :

```
 int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para obtener información de contactos.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A partir de android 6.0 API 23 los permisos se dan el tiempo de ejecucion, checa el siguiente enlace:

[Cómo solicitar permisos durante el tiempo de ejecución](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)